# how to write assertion for asynchronous reset behavior

Tags: system-verilog, assertions, system-verilog-assertions

Lets take a simple example of a d flip flop with asynchronous reset.

q should be updated with d on next edge of clock, this can be written with simple implication operator assertion.

However how to capture reset behavior in assertion.
I've tried following few

```
assert @(posedge rst) (1'b1 |-> !Q);

assert @(posedge rst) (1'b1 ##0 !Q);
```

both these assertions fail, I think because there is no next posedge of rst?

```
assert @(posedge clk) ($rose(rst) |-> !Q);
```

passes but requires free running clock and is asserted between 2 edges of clock (not ann inteded behavior for rst)

```
 assert #0 (not (rst & Q));
```

As per my understanding this is a correct immediate assertion, however I can't see this one passing / failing in waveform viewer. Further more I think I won't be able to write cover on last type of assertion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assertions fails because `Q` is sampled before it is updated. Sampling happens on the LHS of the triggering event, early in the simulator's scheduler. `Q` is updated in the reactive region which is later in the scheduling order.

An easy way to correct this is to add a tiny delay such as SystemVerilog's `1step`. I suggest putting `rst` in the checking condition that can work as a part of a minimum pulse-width check.

```
wire #(1step) rst_delay = rst;
assert @(posedge rst_delay) (1'b1 |-> rst && !Q);
```

If you are simulating with a reset-to-q delay, such as from with SDF annotation or artificial delay, then add the offset to `rst_delay`.

```
wire #(r2q+1step) rst_delay = rst;
assert @(posedge rst_delay) (1'b1 |-> rst && !Q);
```

Comment: Thanks, updated my assertion. preliminary tests are passing. I'll run a suit and see the outcome. Right now I don't need to run it with r2q delays but good to know :)